# CakePHP Illegal string offset

Tags: cakephp

**I am getting the error Illegal string offset.. tried to search on Stackoverflow but they are not helping me..**
**Please Help**

## My Model

> function Fetch() {
>       return   $this->find('list', array('fields' => array('Employee.id',
>       'Employee.firstname','Employee.lastname','Employee.salary')
>       ));
>       }

## My Controller

> public function index(){
>            $this->set('employees',$this->Employee->Fetch());
>
> ```
> }
> ```

## My View

```
  <?php
$id = 0;
foreach($employees as $e):?>
<? $id++ ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $e{'Employee'}{'id'} ?></td>
<td><?php echo $e['Employee']['firstname'], $e['Employee']['lastname'] ?></td>
<td>2014-04-24</td>
<td>2014-04-29</td>
<td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $e['Employee']['salary'] ?></td>'
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

## My Error

```
Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'Employee' [APP\View\Employees\index.ctp, line 19]

Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'id' [APP\View\Employees\index.ctp, line 19]

I   

Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'Employee' [APP\View\Employees\index.ctp, line 20]

Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'firstname' [APP\View\Employees\index.ctp, line 20]

I

Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'Employee' [APP\View\Employees\index.ctp, line 20]

Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'lastname' [APP\View\Employees\index.ctp, line 20]



Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'Employee' [APP\View\Employees\index.ctp, line 23]

Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'salary' [APP\View\Employees\index.ctp, line 23]
```

Comment: paste `index.ctp` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find('all')`. `find('list')` is more suitable when you need only 2 fields retrieved

```
function Fetch() { 
    return $this->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('Employee.id', 'Employee.firstname','Employee.lastname','Employee.salary') )
    ); 
}
```

Then use `$e` like `$e['Employee']['id']` instead of `$e{'Employee'}{'id'}`.

If you are still getting errors, `debug($e)` in the view to see if it's in the correct format

Comment: you need 4 fields. find('list') works like this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list

Comment: `find(list)` works as a `key => value` array. It's more suited for things like `select` options list, etc. So when you iterate over a list-array, `$e` has the value, but the key is lost as you haven't assigned it to a variable.